# Laravel Eloquent 5.4 Model Events

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.3

I use Eloquent in my Project ( I do not use Laravel ) and it works out-the-box as expected. There is only problem, I having trouble setting up the events on the Model.

For example: I wanna do something else when updating the Model or when something is saved in the Model, etc...

Is this code still working in **Eloquent 5.4** ? I did some attempts but failed with this. Probably this doesn't work anymore in **Eloquent 5.4** and I need an alternative to that.

```
class Something extends Model {
    public static function boot() {
        parent::boot();
        static::creating(function($item) {
            $item->uuid = uuid_generate();
        });
    }
}
```

If not I need a solution that is not Laravel-way. Hope its possible to catch these events inside the Model itself.

Comment: Should probably work, but the preferred way has changed. Have a look at the docs here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#events

Comment: The events will be fired, but you will need to register a dispatcher that actually does something with those events since you’re not using Eloquent within Laravel.

Comment: The code above doesn't work, is there anyway to do that and keep it simple ? I need to write this dispatcher ?

Comment: Yes, you need to write the dispatcher. The events system is a separate “component” in Laravel, so if you’re not using Laravel you’re not going to get those components “glued” together, so you’ll need to tell Eloquent of your own application’s event dispatcher and handle those events emitted by Eloquent.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/events A new way to  send the events by class and you can call them on model with https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#events

Comment: @PrashantBarve Care to give an working example ? I already read that and didn't worked what I tried at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
use Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager as Capsule;

$capsule = new Capsule;

$capsule->addConnection([
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => 'localhost',
    'database'  => 'database',
    'username'  => 'root',
    'password'  => 'password',
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => '',
]);

// Set the event dispatcher used by Eloquent models... (optional)
use Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher;
use Illuminate\Container\Container;
$capsule->setEventDispatcher(new Dispatcher(new Container));

// Make this Capsule instance available globally via static methods... (optional)
$capsule->setAsGlobal();

// Setup the Eloquent ORM... (optional; unless you've used setEventDispatcher())
$capsule->bootEloquent();
```

**composer require "illuminate/events" required when you need to use observers with Eloquent.**

You need to setup Eloquent in outside projects like this for the events and observers to work.

**Setting up Events:**

```
class Something extends Model {
    public static function boot() {
        parent::boot();
        static::creating(function($item) {
            $item->uuid = uuid_generate();
        });
    }
}

class Something extends Model {
    protected $events = [ 'created' => createdEvent::class]
}
```

Check the documentation for more but both ways still works in Eloquent 5.4.